# How to use ServiceStack's Request logger without user sessions?

Tags: servicestack

In order to add/enable ServiceStack Request logger following line of code has to be added according ServiceStack github [wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger) documentation.

Is there a way to use the request logger without user sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable tracking sessions when you configure the `RequestLoggerFeature`:

```cs
Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature(){
    EnableSessionTracking = false
});
```